# how to find pdf $f_X(x)$ from joint pdf $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, density-function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKmo1.png)I have joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$. $X$ and $Y$ are dependent random variable. I know that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution. it is hard to integrate joint PDF. are there any method to separate this joint PDF to two identical PDF ?

Comment: What is the joint PDF?

Comment: Please edit $f_{X,\,Y}$ into your question. Someone might know how to integrate out $y$, which is the only way you'll get to $f_X$

Comment: You could estimate the marginal distribution from the joint one numerically.

Comment: the integration of joint PDF is really complex